# emacs - show vertical scrollbar or indicator of position

Tags: emacs, scrollbar

I would like to show my position within a buffer on the left (or right) side of a buffer. For example, if my cursor is 75% of the way down a buffer, I would like to see an indicator 75% of the way down the left hand side of my window.

In a graphical editor, I usually see this as a vertical scroll bar.

However, I run emacs with `--no-window-system`, in my Mac terminal.

Things I've tried:

- `M-x scroll-bar-mode`: doesn't appear to do anything when I launch emacs with `--no-window-system`
- `sml-modeline-mode`: This is nice, but it shows the indicator in the modeline, whereas I want an indicator vertically, up and down the left-hand-side of my buffer.
- `minimap-mode`: displays more than what I want, I just want a vertical indicator of position.
- `indicators.el`: looks promising, but I haven't found something built on top of this that will indicate vertical position

Comment: found `yascroll` as an answer here http://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/17863/what-are-my-options-for-scroll-bars-in-terminal-emacs

Answer (score 2):

`yascroll` suited my needs

https://github.com/m2ym/yascroll-el

found via https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/17863/what-are-my-options-for-scroll-bars-in-terminal-emacs